# Approaches to analyse microbiome of closely related individuals

Tags: multivariate-analysis, distance

I am currently analysing the gut microbiome of 36 birds under a controlled living environment and diet. Some of them have a particular disease, therefore I'd like to analyse whether the microbiome distance between birds with and without the disease are statistically different. The tricky part is that many of these individuals are related. There are many direct sibling pairs among them and many of them are third-degree kins (e.g. siblings of their parents or half siblings that share one of the parents). I have the kinship data that was calculated by SNPs from the genome data of each bird, and have created a kinship distance matrix of those birds. Thus I'm looking for analyses that can be done by using the kinship distance matrix as a control variable, to allow me to analyse the effects of other variables, e.g. disease. I have come across the partial mantel's test, which allow the use of one distance matrix as a control for the analysis of correlation between two other distance matrixes. Yet, since many variables e.g. disease cannot be expressed in a distance matrix unlike microbiome data and kinship data, I don't find it useful. Would anyone please shed some light on this? I'm no statistician and am so confused :< Thank you so much!